# Servlet class instantiation failed (strange)

Tags: servlets, runtime-error

I have written a simple servlet class in eclipse dynamic web project, added servlet-api.jar to its build path but when i try to run it , i get servlet class instantiation error. Help needed

Comment: Could you show the stacktrace?

Comment: oops .. I found the error ..I was providing wrong path for JAVA_HOME

Comment: If we try nothing, we don't make errors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong path for JAVA_HOME was the problem .. my mistake